# Adding a route to route table

Tags: networking, windows-vista, cisco-vpn-client

I have VPN connection to a third part network and when i try to connect to my local network application i cannot access. somebody suggested to add a route to route table. I am new to it. Can somebody help me in getting this setup. I appreciate it.

Comment: could you post what you have in your route table (command `route` on linux or `route PRINT` on windows

Answer (score 1):

What kind of OS are you using? Windows-mac-Linux...
What kind of vpn are you using? pptp-cisco-fortigate...
Why is routing the problem?

My guess is DNS: When VPN is connected the problem is often connecting to names rather than IP-adresses.
This could be solved by adding the local DNS server to the vpn interface or editing the hosts-file (not recommended)

Comment: Window Vista and its Cisco vpn client

Comment: 1: Get the IP-address of your VPN interface (ex:10.22.22.222) 2:Get the subnet of the network you are trying to reach (ex:10.22.23.0/24) 3: Enter the following in the command prompt: add route 10.22.23.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.22.22.222